# Error when search a file in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an error when I have tried search a file get from url. I want to search a file in directory it will match with the value get from url if matched controller will return value 'ok' to browser. But I can not see anything appear in my browser.

**jquery transmit url to server**

```
var qr_download = function(e){
var img = $('#display').attr('src');
if(img == ''){
    alert('Generate a code first!');
    return;
}else{
    var fn = img.substr(img.lastIndexOf('/')+1,img.length-img.lastIndexOf('/'));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'download_file/' + fn,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.error)
                alert('Error: ' + data.error);
            if(data.success)
                alert('Success: ' + data.success);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**my controller**

```
public function download_file($filename){
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $ext = substr(strrchr($filename,'.'),1);
    $list = array();

    if(in_array($ext,array('png','jpg','jpeg'))){
        $files = scandir('temp/');
        for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i]) && !in_array($files[$i],array('.','..'))){
                if($files[$i] == $filename){
                    //$content = file_get_contents(base_url().'temp/'.$files[$i]);
                    //force_download($files[$i],$content);
                    $this->result['success'] = 'ok';
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }//end for
    }else{
        $this->result['error'] = 'Not allowed file type';
    }

    echo json_encode($this->result);
}
```

Please help me resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: double check your path to scan

Comment: Your exit(); will stop the execution of the script, You'll never get the 'OK' output.